# How to dynamically update the record in DynamoDB in Python?

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to update records in dynamodb table dynamically.

table structure is like this:

```
host_name, host_id hostClass column1 column2 column3 column4 .... column10
```

my function is like this:

```
def update_column_info(host_name, host_id, column_name):
    table = self.client.Table(my_test_table)
    try:
        response = table.update_item(
           Key={PARTITION_KEY: str(host_name),
             SORT_KEY: str(host_id)},
             UpdateExpression='SET hostClass=:hostClass',
             ExpressionAttributeValues={':hostClass': column_value}
    except Exception as e:
        print("failed", e)
```

This worked to update column hostClass.

But I am trying to update it dynamically in which I don't need to pass the column name separately and trying to do similar thing which is mentioned in this [post](https://dev.to/dvddpl/dynamodb-dynamic-method-to-insert-or-edit-an-item-5fnh) for javascript.
but I am trying it for python and couldn't figure out the proper syntax.

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact same question and after only having example in JavaScript, I finally figured out how to do it in Python. Hopefully this helps someone out!

Put the attribute (column) and value into a dictionary - this also will allow you to update multiple in a single dynamodb call:

```
attr_to_update = {}
attr_to_update['host_class'] = 'column_value'
```

The following function will use the dictionary you provide, along with the primary key and sort key, to construct an update_item expression for only the attributes you provide. The boto3 resource update_item function will take that object as a parameter and update your table.

```
def update_column_info(host_name, host_id, update_attr):
    table = self.resource.Table(my_test_table)

    # Construct the update expression and attribute values
    update_expression = 'SET '
    exp_att_val = {}

    for key, value in update_attr.items():
        update_expression += f'{key} = :{key}, '
        exp_att_val[f':{key}'] = value

    # Remove trailing comma
    update_expression = update_expression.rstrip(", ")

    # Construct the update_item parameters
    update_item_params = {
        'TableName': 'my_test_table',
        'Key': {
            'host_name': host_name,
            'host_id': host_id
        },
        'UpdateExpression': update_expression,
        'ExpressionAttributeValues': exp_att_val,
        'ReturnValues': 'UPDATED_NEW'
    }

    try:
        # Execute the update_item operation
        response = table.update_item(**update_item_params)
        return response
    except Exception as e:
        print("failed", e)
```

Calling the function as follows:

```
update_column_info('host_name', 'host_id', attr_to_update)
```

Yields the following Update Item expression:

```
{'TableName': 'my_test_table', 'Key': {'host_name': 'host_name', 'host_id': 'host_id'}, 'UpdateExpression': 'SET host_class = :host_class', 'ExpressionAttributeValues': {':host_class': 'column_value'}, 'ReturnValues': 'UPDATED_NEW'}
```